# Asking to self-answer a more or less common problem

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I have problem `abc`, with language `ghi` and system `jkl`, which has its own forums at `www.thereisaforumhere.com/nottherealsite`. Although it isn't a large part of Stack Overflow and questions asked here, it is a major oversight within the system and the system forums are filled with "what did I do wrong" style threads.

Would it be appropriate for me to ask a question here, to self-answer it, with the problem and solution, and then provide links on the forum?

Or, since it isn't very popular on Stack Overflow, would it be better suited to post on that forum and hope a moderator stickies it?

Comment: Self-answering is fine. The only problem you're alluding to is if your question is too-localized. We can't answer that without knowing what the topic/tag is. But even if it's closed as too-localized your content will still be there ready to help someone.

Comment: @MikeB: Yes, but I am skating on thin ice regarding the auto-question-ban, and don't want a single closed question to re-ban me. And a single closed question could very easily re-ban me.

Comment: Posting a question on a Meta site to ask about the exact text of a potential main site question is considered okay. If you're concerned about closure, you should be able to get either feedback here, either as suggestions or at least thumbs up/down.

Comment: The fundamental idea of self-answering a canonical question is okay, but doing it correctly is *hard*, most people aren't able to write quality self-answered questions, thus posting the specifics here is really needed for us to tell you if you're question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Another way to go is to find an existing question and answer that instead. Editing to make it more generic might also help but you'll need to get to 2K rep first

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter, I can suggest edits, but cannot be the only editor/reviewer yet. I have 75% of my meta reputation on the main site.